# MySQL> Selecting from more tables (with same columns) without UNION

Tags: mysql, select

It is probably pretty simple but I cannot figure it out: Say I have tables A and B both with the same columns. I need to do SELECT * FROM A,B without having results merged into one row.
I.e. when each table has 2 rows, I need the result to have 4 rows.
EDIT: I know about JOIN but dont know how to join the tables without predicate. I need merge them.
Thanks

Comment: This is called a cartesian product, it's usually something bad.
There is no way to do it in SQL without UNION!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2 FROM B
```

UNION ALL allows duplicates.

Whereas UNION removes duplicates.

Comment: Yep but I was asking without UNION (it is in the title :)

Comment: Yes but I am intersted in different method of doing that - without using UNION.